# Conditional div with a variable in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails view where I generate a div conditionally if a local variable is defined. Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<%= '<div class="search_wrapper_inner #{group_class}" >'.html_safe if defined?(group_class) %>
```

However, the string interpolation obviously fails because of the html_safe and produces the following...

```
<div class= "search_wrapper_inner #{group_class}">
```

how can I add a variable class to a conditionally generated div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start off with double quotes and not single quotes for string interpolation to work.  Try:

```
<%= "<div class='search_wrapper_inner #{group_class}' >".html_safe if defined?(group_class) %>
```

Here is the test for it in rails console:

```
> group_class = "test"
 => "test" 

> '<div class="search_wrapper_inner #{group_class}" >'.html_safe
 => "<div class=\"search_wrapper_inner \#{group_class}\" >" 

> "<div class='search_wrapper_inner #{group_class}' >".html_safe
 => "<div class='search_wrapper_inner test' >"
```